# how to use pg_connect to connect to 2 different postgresql databases on the same computer

Tags: php, postgresql

I am trying to use 2 instances of postgresql database on the same computer. any idea how should i use pg_connect

I was able to connect to one instance of postgresql  using pg_connect successfully. However I have created a second instance for a new web application. How to specify parameter to connect to both databases on the same php code using pg_connect.

Comment: If you have 2 DB instances on same host they should to use different ports (default port: 5432 and some other port). Use different ports to connect to different DB instances. Another case if you have two databases at single server you should use DB names in you connection string. 
Any case you must provide more information for some one will help you.

Answer (score 2):

It is literally the first example given on php.net reference page for  [pg_connect](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-connect.php)

```
$dbconn = pg_connect("dbname=mary");
//connect to a database named "mary"

$dbconn2 = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=mary");
// connect to a database named "mary" on "localhost" at port "5432"

$dbconn3 = pg_connect("host=sheep port=5432 dbname=mary user=lamb password=foo");
//connect to a database named "mary" on the host "sheep" with a username and password
```

Just change the connection string and declare multiple connection objects and you should be fine

Comment: this is a old question. thank you for your code example. it helped me a lot. thank you.